# boost asio tcp connection no received data after reconnecting and reading

Tags: c++, boost, tcp, boost-asio, tcpclient

I am using boost asio to connect to a TCP Server.
When I run the code it works fine after start. I send the request and get the response.
When I turn off the tcp server (it is a device) I am running into timeout and callback inside async_read from boost will never be executed when I am running into timeout. Then I close the socket. After turn on the device the connection could be re-established but then the recived buffer size is 0 bytes. I think thats because the async_read was not finished correctly after timeout.

header

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/format.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <future>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>


class TcpClient{
    public:
        int connect(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket &socket, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint &endpoint);
        int writeAndRead(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket &socket);

};
```

This is the code

```
#include "tcpclient.h"

int TcpClient::connect(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket &socket, boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint &endpoint)
{
    boost::system::error_code error;
    socket.connect(endpoint, error);
    if (!error)
    {
        std::cout << "connected" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "not connected" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
}

int TcpClient::writeAndRead(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket &socket)
{

    boost::system::error_code error;
    auto status = std::async(std::launch::async, [&]()
                             { boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer("mytext"), error); })
                      .wait_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{1000});

    switch (status)
    {
    case std::future_status::deferred:
        std::cout << "std::future_status::deferred" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    case std::future_status::ready:
        std::cout << "write success" << std::endl;
        break;
    case std::future_status::timeout:
        std::cout << "std::future_status::timeout" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    boost::asio::streambuf receive_buffer;
    boost::optional<boost::system::error_code> read_result;
    boost::optional<boost::system::error_code> timer_result;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer(socket.get_io_service());

    timer.expires_from_now(boost::posix_time::seconds(2));

    timer.async_wait([&timer_result](const boost::system::error_code &error)
                     {
        if (error != boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
        {
            timer_result = error;
        } });

    boost::asio::async_read(socket,
                            receive_buffer,
                            boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
                            [&read_result](const boost::system::error_code &ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred)
                            {
                                std::cout << "read_result: " << read_result << std::endl;
                                read_result = ec;
                            });
    boost::system::error_code ec;

    while (1)
    {
        socket.get_io_service().reset();
        int numHandlers = socket.get_io_service().poll_one(ec);
        if (read_result)
        {
            timer.cancel();
            break;
        }
        else if (timer_result)
        {
            timer.cancel();
            std::cout << "timeout" << std::endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    if (receive_buffer.size() == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "receive_buffer size 0" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    std::string rawResponse = boost::asio::buffer_cast<const char *>(receive_buffer.data());
    std::cout << "rawResponse: " << rawResponse << std::endl;
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    std::string ipAddress = "192.168.2.4";
    unsigned short port = 50001;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address::from_string(ipAddress), port);
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket{ioService};
    bool isSuccess{false};
    bool isConnected{false};
    TcpClient tcpclient = TcpClient();

    while (1)
    {
        if (!isConnected)
        {
            isConnected = tcpclient.connect(socket, endpoint);
        }
        if (isConnected)
        {
            isSuccess = tcpclient.writeAndRead(socket);
            if (!isSuccess)
            {
                std::cout << "failed close socket" << std::endl;
                socket.close();
                isConnected = false;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout << "success" << std::endl;
            }
        }
        std::cout << "wait for 1 sec" << std::endl;
        std::chrono::seconds dura(1);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(dura);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

this is the output

```
success
wait for 1 sec
write success
read_result: 0
rawResponse: 0;

success
wait for 1 sec
write success
timeout
failed close socket
wait for 1 sec
not connected
wait for 1 sec
not connected
wait for 1 sec
not connected
wait for 1 sec
not connected
wait for 1 sec
connected
write success
read_result: 0
receive_buffer size 0
failed close socket
wait for 1 sec
connected
write success
read_result: 0
receive_buffer size 0
failed close socket
```

Comment: "... the received buffer size is 0 bytes": this really means that `recv()` returned zero, which in turn indicates that the peer has closed the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Asio is an asynchronous IO library.

You're using the blocking API with std::async to ... fake asynchronous IO. I'd suggest not doing that. It looks like your code is based on (very) old example code. `get_io_service()` is long gone and `io_service` itself is only available as part of deprecated API.

I don't know what compiler you have access to, but this is how I'd write the same code now:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3421a953924dacdd)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/experimental/awaitable_operators.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using Socket = asio::use_awaitable_t<>::as_default_on_t<tcp::socket>;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;
using namespace asio::experimental::awaitable_operators;

asio::awaitable<void> delay(std::chrono::steady_clock::duration dur) {
    auto ex = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
    co_await asio::steady_timer(ex, dur).async_wait(asio::deferred);
}

asio::awaitable<void> requestLoop(Socket& socket) {
    for (std::string request = "test", response;;) {
        if (auto r = co_await (async_write(socket, asio::buffer(request)) || delay(1s)); r.index()) {
            std::cout << "write timeout" << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        auto r = co_await ( //
            asio::async_read(socket, asio::dynamic_buffer(response), asio::transfer_at_least(1),
                             as_tuple(asio::use_awaitable)) ||
            delay(2s));
        if (r.index()) {
            std::cout << "read timeout" << std::endl;
            break;
        }

        auto [ec, bytes] = get<0>(r);

        std::cout << "Response: " << quoted(response) << " (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
    }
}

asio::awaitable<void> client(std::string ipAddress, uint16_t port) {
    auto ex = co_await asio::this_coro::executor;
    for (;; co_await delay(1s)) {
        try {
            Socket socket(ex);
            co_await socket.async_connect({asio::ip::address::from_string(ipAddress), port});
            std::cout << "Connected to " << socket.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;

            co_await requestLoop(socket);
        } catch (boost::system::system_error const& se) {
            std::cout << "Error: " << se.code().message() << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    asio::io_context ioc;
    //co_spawn(ioc, client("192.168.1.1", 8045), asio::detached);
    co_spawn(ioc, client("0.0.0.0", 8045), asio::detached);
    ioc.run();
}
```

With a local demo:

[image]

### UPDATE: C++11, Boost 1.53, Single Threading

In response to the added context in the comment, here an time-traveling version that ... well goes back in time :)

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/hxnv1cdeK)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio   = boost::asio;
namespace chrono = std::chrono;
using asio::ip::tcp;
using std::placeholders::_1;

struct TcpClient {
    TcpClient(std::string ipAddress, uint16_t port) //
        : ep_{asio::ip::address::from_string(ipAddress), port} {}

    void run() {
        do_connect();
        ios_.run();
    }

  private:
    using error_code = boost::system::error_code;
    asio::io_service   ios_;
    tcp::endpoint      ep_;
    tcp::socket        socket_{ios_};
    asio::steady_timer timer_{ios_};
    std::string        request_ = "hello";
    asio::streambuf    buffer_;

    void start_reconnect() {
        if (socket_.is_open()) {
            error_code ignore;
            socket_.close(ignore);
        }
        timer_.expires_from_now(chrono::seconds(1));
        timer_.async_wait(bind(&TcpClient::do_connect, this, _1));
    }

    void do_connect(error_code ec = {}) {
        if (!ec)
            socket_.async_connect(ep_, bind(&TcpClient::on_connect, this, _1));
    }

    void on_connect(error_code ec) {
        if (ec) {
            std::cout << "Error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            return start_reconnect();
        }
        do_request_loop();
    }

    void do_request_loop() {
        timer_.expires_from_now(chrono::seconds(1));
        timer_.async_wait(bind(&TcpClient::on_timeout, this, _1));

        async_write(socket_, asio::buffer(request_), bind(&TcpClient::on_request_sent, this, _1));
    }

    void on_request_sent(error_code ec) {
        if (ec) {
            std::cout << "Error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            return start_reconnect();
        }

        timer_.expires_from_now(chrono::seconds(2));
        timer_.async_wait(bind(&TcpClient::on_timeout, this, _1));

        async_read(socket_, buffer_, asio::transfer_at_least(1),
                   bind(&TcpClient::on_response_received, this, _1));
    }

    void on_response_received(error_code ec) {
        if (ec) {
            std::cout << "Error: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            return start_reconnect();
        }
        std::string response(buffers_begin(buffer_.data()), buffers_end(buffer_.data()));
        std::cout << "Response: \"" << response << "\" (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
        do_request_loop();
    }

    void on_timeout(error_code ec) {
        if (!ec) {
            std::cout << "Timed out" << std::endl;
            socket_.cancel();
        }
    }
};

int main() {
    TcpClient client("0.0.0.0", 8045);
    client.run();
}
```

With the equivalent demo:

[image]

## BONUS: Faux Coroutines

Just remembered that with the [magic](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/composition/coroutine.html) of "faux coroutines" you can write the c++11/boost 1.53 version hiding the callbacks and simulating normal control flow:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://compiler-explorer.com/z/Enddde8Ye)**

```cpp
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/coroutine.hpp>
#include <boost/asio/steady_timer.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace asio = boost::asio;

void run_client(asio::io_service& ios, std::string ipAddress, uint16_t port) {
    using asio::ip::tcp;
    using boost::system::error_code;
    using std::chrono::seconds;

    struct Impl {
        Impl(asio::io_service& ios, tcp::endpoint ep) : st_(std::make_shared<State>(ios, ep)) {}

        struct State : std::enable_shared_from_this<State> {
            State(asio::io_service& ios, tcp::endpoint ep) : s(ios), ep_(ep), timer_(ios) {}

            asio::coroutine    coro;
            tcp::socket        s;
            tcp::endpoint      ep_;
            asio::steady_timer timer_;
            std::string        request_ = "hello";
            asio::streambuf    buffer_;

            void deadline(asio::steady_timer::duration d) {
                timer_.expires_from_now(d);
                timer_.async_wait(bind(&State::on_timer, shared_from_this(), std::placeholders::_1));
            }

          private:
            void on_timer(error_code ec) {
                if (!ec) {
                    std::cout << "Timed out" << std::endl;
                    s.cancel();
                }
            }
        };
        std::shared_ptr<State> st_ ;

#include <boost/asio/yield.hpp>
        void operator()(error_code ec = {}, size_t /*bytes_transferred*/ = {}) {
            reenter(st_->coro) {
                for (;;) {
                    yield st_->s.async_connect(st_->ep_, std::move(*this));

                    std::cout << "Connection to " << st_->ep_ << " " << ec.message() << std::endl;

                    while (!ec) {
                        st_->deadline(seconds(1));
                        yield async_write(st_->s, asio::buffer(st_->request_), std::move(*this));

                        std::cout << "Written: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                        if (ec) break;

                        st_->deadline(seconds(2));
                        yield async_read(st_->s, st_->buffer_, asio::transfer_at_least(1), std::move(*this));

                        std::cout << "Read: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                        if (ec) break;

                        std::string response(buffers_begin(st_->buffer_.data()),
                                             buffers_end(st_->buffer_.data()));
                        std::cout << "Response: \"" << response << "\" (" << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;
                    }

                    // close the connection
                    st_->s.close(ec);

                    // wait 1s before reconnecting
                    st_->timer_.expires_from_now(seconds(1));
                    yield st_->timer_.async_wait(std::move(*this));
                }
            }
        }
#include <boost/asio/unyield.hpp>
    };

    ios.post(Impl(ios, {asio::ip::address::from_string(ipAddress), port}));
}

int main() {
    asio::io_service ios(1);
    run_client(ios, "0.0.0.0", 8045);
    ios.run();
}
```

With yet another equivalent demo:

[image]

Comment: thanks but this does not really help. I am using boost version 1.53.0 and gnu compiler. I cant update boost on that system

Comment: maybe shared_from_this is missing? But I dont know how to use it inside lambda function

Comment: I am using async because I need a timeout

Comment: `std::async` is NOT async IO. It's blocking IO on more threads. Also, you don't control how many threads. That is recipe for deadlock. If you really want to be using async and *undisclosed version of gnu compiler*, just use the async IO interfaces. Do not create a complicated mess with restarted io services, threads and futures just to compensate, as it leads to the complications you are having. I'll probably look later

Comment: Here you go, completely c++11 version tested with gcc 7.4 and Boost 1.53: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/hxnv1cdeK Interactive Demo: https://imgur.com/a/y4qW3OK. Note how it uses ZERO threads (well, unless the main thread always counts) and true async IO. Much less complex. No funny manual polling and boolean state flags all over the place. #simple wins the day

Comment: Just remembered that with some [magic](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/composition/coroutine.html) you can write the c++11/boost 1.53 version hiding the callbacks and simulating normal control flow: https://compiler-explorer.com/z/Enddde8Ye with yet another equivalent demo https://imgur.com/a/JTM1dvs