boost beast async read argument overload or mismatching
 AsyncReadStream& stream,
 DynamicBuffer& buffer,
 basic_parser< isRequest >& parser,
 ReadHandler&& handler = net::default_completion_token_t< executor_type< AsyncReadStream > >{});

based on the above, am i missing something with my below async read? since no
instance of overload function error is been thrown
void hook::connector(std::string id){
    boost::system::error_code ec;
    
    auto stream_socket=std::make_shared<boost::beast::tcp_stream>(boost::asio::make_strand(ioc));

    boost::beast::flat_buffer read_buffer;

    boost::beast::http::request<boost::beast::http::string_body> con_req;

    boost::beast::http::response<boost::beast::http::string_body> con_res;

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endP = this->select_endP(servers[id].endpoint_pool, servers[id].domain);

    stream_socket->expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

    try {
        stream_socket->async_connect(endP, [this, id, stream_socket,&read_buffer,con_req, con_res](boost::system::error_code ec) {
            if (!ec) {
                std::cout << "Connected to server!" << std::endl;

                stream_socket->expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

                boost::beast::http::async_write(*stream_socket,con_req,
                    [this, id, stream_socket,&read_buffer,con_req,con_res](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
                        boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);
                        
                        if (!ec) {

                            read_buffer.clear();



//error is being raised from this snippet
                            boost::beast::http::async_read(*stream_socket,read_buffer,con_res,[this,id,con_res](boost::system::error_code ec,std::size_t transfered_size){
                                boost::ignore_unused(transfered_size);

                                if(!ec){
                                    //success
                                } else{
                                    //failure
                                };

                            });

                            if (con_req.need_eof()) {

                                boost::beast::error_code shutdown_ec;

                                stream_socket->socket().shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_send, shutdown_ec);

                                if(shutdown_ec) {

                                    cout << "Error shutting down: " << shutdown_ec.message() << endl;

                                }
                            };

                        } else {
                            std::cout << "Error writing: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                            // Retry the connection on failure
                        }
                    }
                );
            } else {
                std::cout << "Error connecting: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                // Retry the connection on failure
            }
        });
    } catch (const std::exception& e) {
        std::cout << "Error with read and write: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }

};


You are capturing several objects by value, in immutable lambdas. Besides this not doing what you need, it also means that the objects are const (immutable).
That's why con_res is not usable with async_read: it cannot be converted to a mutable reference to a message object (or parser).
A hap-hazard way to "fix" the compiler error is to make the lambdas mutable:
Live On Coliru
Live On Compiler Explorer (both run out of resources)
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http = beast::http;
using asio::ip::tcp;

struct hook {
    void             connector(std::string id);
    asio::io_context ioc;

    struct Server {
        std::string                domain;
        std::vector<tcp::endpoint> endpoint_pool;
    };

    std::map<std::string, Server> servers{
        {"test",
         Server{
             "www.google.com",
             {
                 {tcp::endpoint{{}, 8989}},
                 {tcp::endpoint{{}, 9090}},
                 {tcp::endpoint{{}, 9191}},
             },
         }},
    };

    tcp::endpoint select_endP(std::vector<tcp::endpoint> const& endpoint_pool, std::string /*domain*/) {
        return endpoint_pool[0]; // TODO: implement selection logic
    }
};

void hook::connector(std::string id) {
    boost::system::error_code ec;

    auto stream_socket = std::make_shared<beast::tcp_stream>(make_strand(ioc));

    beast::flat_buffer read_buffer;

    http::request<http::string_body> con_req;
    http::response<http::string_body> con_res;

    tcp::endpoint endP = this->select_endP(servers[id].endpoint_pool, servers[id].domain);

    stream_socket->expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

    try {
        stream_socket->async_connect(
            endP, [this, id, stream_socket, &read_buffer, con_req, con_res](boost::system::error_code ec) {
                if (!ec) {
                    std::cout << "Connected to server!" << std::endl;

                    stream_socket->expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

                    http::async_write(
                        *stream_socket, con_req,
                        [this, id, stream_socket, &read_buffer, con_req,
                         con_res](beast::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) mutable {
                            boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

                            if (!ec) {

                                read_buffer.clear();

                                // error is being raised from this snippet
                                http::async_read(
                                    *stream_socket, read_buffer, con_res,
                                    [this, id /*, con_res*/](beast::error_code ec,
                                                             std::size_t       transfered_size) mutable {
                                        boost::ignore_unused(transfered_size);

                                        if (!ec) {
                                            // success
                                        } else {
                                            // failure
                                        };
                                    });

                                if (con_req.need_eof()) {

                                    beast::error_code shutdown_ec;

                                    stream_socket->socket().shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_send, shutdown_ec);

                                    if (shutdown_ec) {

                                        std::cout << "Error shutting down: " << shutdown_ec.message()
                                                  << std::endl;
                                    }
                                };

                            } else {
                                std::cout << "Error writing: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                                // Retry the connection on failure
                            }
                        });
                } else {
                    std::cout << "Error connecting: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                    // Retry the connection on failure
                }
            });
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << "Error with read and write: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    hook h;
    h.connector("test");
}

However, in reality you will always just end up with empty copues of con_req and con_res. What you really want is for those to be shared. E.g.:
Live On Coliru
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/beast.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
namespace asio = boost::asio;
namespace beast = boost::beast;
namespace http = beast::http;
using asio::ip::tcp;

struct hook {
    void              connector(std::string id);
    asio::thread_pool ioc;

    struct Server {
        std::string                domain;
        std::vector<tcp::endpoint> endpoint_pool;
    };

    std::map<std::string, Server> servers{
        {"test",
         Server{
             "www.google.com",
             {
                 {tcp::endpoint{{}, 8989}},
                 {tcp::endpoint{{}, 9090}},
                 {tcp::endpoint{{}, 9191}},
             },
         }},
    };

    tcp::endpoint select_endP(std::vector<tcp::endpoint> const& endpoint_pool, std::string /*domain*/) {
        return endpoint_pool[0]; // TODO: implement selection logic
    }
};

void hook::connector(std::string id) {
    struct Con {
        beast::tcp_stream                 stream_socket;
        std::string                       id;
        beast::flat_buffer                read_buffer = {};
        http::request<http::string_body>  con_req= {};
        http::response<http::string_body> con_res     = {};
    };
    auto state = std::make_shared<Con>(Con{beast::tcp_stream{make_strand(ioc)}, id});

    tcp::endpoint endP = this->select_endP(servers[id].endpoint_pool, servers[id].domain);

    state->stream_socket.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

    try {
        state->stream_socket.async_connect(
            endP, [state, id](boost::system::error_code ec) {
                if (!ec) {
                    std::cout << "Connected to server!" << std::endl;

                    state->stream_socket.expires_after(std::chrono::seconds(30));

                    http::async_write(
                        state->stream_socket, state->con_req,
                        [id, state](beast::error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) mutable {
                            boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

                            if (!ec) {

                                state->read_buffer.clear();

                                // error is being raised from this snippet
                                http::async_read(
                                    state->stream_socket, state->read_buffer, state->con_res,
                                    [state, id](beast::error_code ec, size_t transfered_size) mutable {
                                        boost::ignore_unused(transfered_size);

                                        if (!ec) {
                                            // success
                                        } else {
                                            // failure
                                        };
                                    });

                                if (state->con_req.need_eof()) {

                                    beast::error_code shutdown_ec;

                                    state->stream_socket.socket().shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_send,
                                                                           shutdown_ec);

                                    if (shutdown_ec) {
                                        std::cout << "Error shutting down: " << shutdown_ec.message()
                                                  << std::endl;
                                    }
                                };

                            } else {
                                std::cout << "Error writing: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                                // Retry the connection on failure
                            }
                        });
                } else {
                    std::cout << "Error connecting: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                    // Retry the connection on failure
                }
            });
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cout << "Error with read and write: " << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    hook h;
    h.connector("test");
}

Of course, as you already half-realized (since you captured this) it makes more sense for the operations to be a part of the Con class.

compiled successfully. thank you. it makes sense to capture all the wrap than individually . How does capturing "this" affect the snippet?

It would start to look like any of the beast/asio examples :) https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/08e1bebb68e2e4bf

If you can use c++20, please consider writing the same using coroutines, way simpler: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/064eec2a141b4e45. I have an older answer that specifically includes reconnect logic: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78127345/85371 (it even shows version in case you cannot use C++20 by the way)

thanks i think the coroutine technique is better. Ofcourse coroutines have the tendency to continue from where they stopped but then what other advantages does it have over the normal boost beast examples? cause all seems to work well when coroutine is not really crucial like a proxy which replays request to another server

They're equivalent, just far easier to write with respect to lifetimes and thread safety
